# Magento 2 subcategories not showing its own products/description

Tags: magento-2.1, category-products

I am working on a magento 2.1 site and for some subcategories it is showing the title, description and products from the parent category not it's own.

If I move the category under another parent category it changes to that parent instead.

It wont list it's own products etc but I cant see anything to control this?

Comment: Further to this when I go to the category instead of loading the category page it appears to loads a filter instead

Answer (score 0):

Solved - This looks to be caused by a layered navigation plugin disabled that and its now working again.